longtable overfull \hbox with S column and shifted text
I'm working on a longtable environment and already had a few suggestions on how to improve it an fix few issues.
Now, I moved on and populated the table but I'm gettin an Overfull \hbox warning potentially related to the size of cells' content and the S column type (I guess).
I do like the idea of having math style formatting and alignment for numbers but I would like to avoid the warnings... is there a way to fix this retaining the current style? Below, a view of the structure and the related code:

\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\smallerbaseline\bfseries} p{0.20\linewidth} *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
}
\caption[\textbf{Graphs metrics for the \texttt{minigraph-CACTUS} and the \texttt{PGGB} toy-model pangenomes}]{\textbf{Graphs metrics for the \texttt{minigraph-CACTUS} and the \texttt{PGGB} toy-model pangenomes.} Most relevant set of metrics to describe pangenome graphs as per <reference>, the Total length and the Estimated sequence length are both in bp. All values have been derived from \texttt{BandageNG}.}
\label{table:graphs} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{GRAPH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\texttt{minigraph-CACTUS}}  
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\texttt{PGGB}} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}

& {\textit{GRCh38-only}} & {\textit{CHM13}} & {\textit{GRCh38-only}} & {\textit{CHM13}} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}

Node Count & 53471400 & 57987367 &  & 61863301 \\
Edge Count & 73629600 & 80019027 &  & 85339313 \\
Total length & 790625239 & 975120756 &  & 0 \\
Dead ends & 10726 & 10717 &  & 5711 \\
Connected components & 4539 & 4549 &  & 408 \\
Median depth & 3 & 3 &  & 12 \\
Estimated sequence length & 5085592535 & 5270088052 &  & 4197455394 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

Also, is it normal that the table doesn't stretch to the textwidth as the caption does? Moreover, is there a way to vertically center the number in the cells where the text is wrapped e.g. Connected components and Estimated Sequence length? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Your numbers seem to have way more digits than the 2.2 you say they have. Change this to an appropriate setting like 10.0. If you want your table to stretch to the textwidth, use some kind of table which can stretch, e.g. longtblr from the tabularray package instead of a longtable. This would also solve your vertical alignment problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh sorry I feel very stupid I even checked up what the table-format=2.2 meant but I completely overlooked it! Any suggestion for the vertical centering, will it entail to create a new cell rule?

For the vertical centering: look up what a p column is what other column types there are https://texdoc.org/serve/array/0

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks again I fixed it with m. V. useful indeed the link you shared I was looking into https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf but couldn't find any reference to the column types...
